# Escaping Multiple Spaces in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

How does Python escape space? I know `\b` backspace one space but how can I backspace multiple spaces? 
For example, I want to use the following code to print out a statement on one line. However, the output shows
the space in front of "door 2." How can I eliminate that wide space?

```
    print "You enter a dark room with two doors. Do you go through door 1 or \
           door 2."
```

Comment: If you are splitting up your string over multiple lines because you don't want to exceed a max line length, use implicit line joining instead. http://pastebin.com/KayLFATQ

Comment: Why not make that an answer? Seems like the best way.

Comment: @RyPeck because it's not an answer to the question asked. It's most likely what Dombey wants to do though.

Comment: @ Dennis What's implicit line joining?

Comment: @Dombey it's when you join lines of strings but not explicitly, e.g. you don't use `str.join` or `+`. BTW, for me to get notified of your mention, the @ has to be attached to my username.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put the extra spaces on the `door 2` line. You don't need to indent lines that are continued by escaping the return character...

```
if True:
    print "You enter a dark room with two doors. Do you go through door 1 or \
door 2."
```

Comment: Well, I thought it's good practice in Python to indent 4 spaces, especially if you have code that runs multiple lines.

Comment: Indentation is not based just on good practice, but it is part of the syntax in python, and the best practice is the one that makes your code work. You could add a baby indentation by putting the return after the `or`, and then the space on the next line: `door 1 or\ door 2.` If you use `print("first part" "second part")` with `"second part"` on the next line, then that is implicit line joining as Dennis suggested.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know practical it would be to do it that way because of indentation levels changing etc and because it's generally not as obvious to read, however a way I commonly see (and use) is:

```
print( "Hi all this is a multiline "
       + "print statement using '+'"
       + " to join the strings" )
```

I know it's probably a bit more awkward but it does look nicer doesn't it :)

Comment: You don't need to concatenate strings using `+` for multi-line strings.